# Micronaut post json body using RxHttpClient

Tags: json, micronaut

How to execute a post call in Micronaut having a json body. The execute method is below but how do we pass json and make this work.

```
    
      HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = new SimpleHttpRequest<String>(HttpMethod.POST, "https://someurl", json);

      return rxHttpClient.exchange(httpRequest, String.class).blockingFirst().body().toString();
  
   }
```

Comment: "How to execute a post call in Micronaut having a json body. " - There are numerous ways to construct initiate a post request from Micronaut and most of them include support a json body.  If you have a specific question you can add that.  For general info, please see https://docs.micronaut.io/3.3.3/guide/#clientPostRequests.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it.  One is with something like the following:

```
def json = '{"town":"St. Louis"}'
client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.POST('/some/uri', json))
```